# How could we get the community site administrator's information in APEX or SOQL

Tags: community

I need to get the site admin's email and send error message into their email box.
How could I get it in APEX?
As far as I know, we can get the networkId as the community identifier in that context.

Comment: How is your community administrator defined?

Comment: Have you tried to use the **networkId** for your community and the **profileId** for admins in that community to see who is assigned to that community?

Comment: I think you can use the **NetworkMember** object here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each community has a site and you can query admin info from site as below:

```
select Id, MasterLabel, SiteType, UrlPathPrefix, AdminId, Admin.Email from site where UrlPathPrefix = '<your community URL prefix>'
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_site.htm